# React: Typescript or Babel error - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have a custom hook and it works great! However, I'm getting Typescript errors if I simply use *React.useState* and *React.useEffect*. To fix this, I import in React and use (React as any).useState and (React as any).useEffect and then I get the following error that doesn't let me compile.

Hook:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import imageApi from 'xcel-api-generator/dist/image';

export const useUserProfileImage = (size, userProfileImage) => {
  const [userImage, setUserImage] = (React as any).useState(null);
    (React as any).useEffect(() => {
      const runEffect = async () => {
        const userImageCall = await imageApi.getTypeByImageType( {"imageType": size} )
        setUserImage(userImageCall.url);
      };
      
      runEffect();
    }, [userProfileImage])
  return [userImage]
}
```

Error:

```js
../rsv8-components/src/hooks/userProfileImage.ts 5:43
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:43)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export const useUserProfileImage = (size, userProfileImage) => {
>   const [userImage, setUserImage] = (React as any).useState(null);
|     (React as any).useEffect(() => {
|       const runEffect = async () => {
```

I'm totally clueless when it comes to webpack/babel etc... Could someone help guide me through this! Thanks!

Here is my local package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "rsv8-components",
  "version": "0.3.11",
  "main": "./dist/module.js",
  "types": "./dist/module.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-avatar-editor": "^10.3.5",
    "react-avatar-editor": "^12.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-scroll-to": "^1.2.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "react-slick-deux": "https://github.com/aboorde/react-slick-deux#master",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "xcel-observer": "*"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-toastify": "^4.1.0",
    "recompose": "^0.28.1",
    "styled-components": "^2.4.0",
    "xcel-asset-service": "*",
    "xcel-react-animations": "*",
    "xcel-react-core": "*",
    "xcel-redux-orm": "*",
    "xcel-util": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "fix-me-test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject",
    "dist": "tsc --declaration",
    "dist:watch": "tsc --declaration --watch",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -c .storybook"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "//": "peerDependencies",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^4.0.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.3.16",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-cli": "^23.4.1",
    "jest-styled-components": "4.9.0",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts-ts": "^3.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "^4.1.0",
    "recompose": "^0.28.1",
    "styled-components": "^2.4.0",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.0",
    "xcel-asset-service": "*",
    "xcel-react-animations": "*",
    "xcel-react-core": "*",
    "xcel-redux-orm": "*",
    "xcel-util": "*"
  },
  "jest": {
    "coverageReporters": [
      "lcov",
      "cobertura",
      "text-summary"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.(ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.(ts|tsx)",
      "!<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.(ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    }
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "Blah blah removed"
  }
}
```